# TypeScript: exclude only exact {} from union

Tags: typescript

I have a union type like:

```
type T = {} | ({ some: number } & { any: string })
```

Then how can I narrow this type to the latter? Of course this didn't work:

```
type WithEntries = Exclude<T, {}>
```

resulting in `never`.

Is this possible?

Comment: `{}` is any object. What you are trying to do has no sense. What are you trying to achieve really?

Comment: T is yielded by type inference. I have an object property whose type is infered as something like T above, and accessing `some` emits an error like "Property 'some' does not exist on type '{}'."

Comment: I think I got you. Wait a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go

```
type T = {} | ({ some: number } & { any: string })

type X<T> = T extends {} ? ({} extends T ? never : T) : never;

type WithEntries = X<T>; //  { some: number; } & { any: string; }
```

The first condition '[distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types)' parts of the union type, so that the second condition can 'filter out' empty type by converting it to `never`, the result is union of `never | (non-empty parts of T)`, and union `never | P` is just `P` for any `P`.

The idea comes [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/43848).

Comment: Ooh looks pretty complicated but suits my use case. Thanks!